have your guys tried bettercallsol tool to to call program from web page?
I trying to use https://bettercallsol.dev/ as a GUI to call program on mainnet.
I import my IDL and pick one method to be run, filled accounts and data that use Borsh style,
click 'send' got error: Uncaught TypeError: vr.toArrayLike is not a function

index.js:37 Uncaught TypeError: vr.toArrayLike is not a function
    at tr.encode (index.js:37:37)
    at Structure$1.encode (Layout.js:1263:26)
    at ho.encode (borsh.ts:28:27)    // 
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (internal-to-web3js.ts:22:20), <anonymous>:1:10)
    at internal-to-web3js.ts:22:20
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Wn (internal-to-web3js.ts:14:31)
    at n (useSendWeb3Transaction.ts:54:7)
    at u (useSendWeb3Transaction.ts:93:40)
    at useWeb3TranasctionBuilder.ts:147:15
    at O (SendButton.tsx:204:7)
    at Object.Nb (react-dom.production.min.js:54:317)
    at Tb (react-dom.production.min.js:54:471)
    at Ub (react-dom.production.min.js:55:35)
    at nf (react-dom.production.min.js:105:68)
    at se$1 (react-dom.production.min.js:106:380)
    at react-dom.production.min.js:117:104
    at Rk (react-dom.production.min.js:274:42)
    at Jb (react-dom.production.min.js:52:375)
    at hd (react-dom.production.min.js:109:469)

In my method, there are u64 and u32 type arguments, the error raise from serialize u64 type argument.
Can anyone show me the correct way to use this tool?

Figure it out, it is bug. vr.toArrayLike is a function of BigNumber type data and the bettercallsol did not convert user input of u64 type to BigNumber, that is the cause of error.
